# PHP PDO: How to insert multiple rows?

Tags: php, sql, pdo

I've many sql statements but I want but I wonder if there is any method or function to shorten and do it in the fewest possible lines using PHP PDO.

One idea I have is to create an array with the following names: Perfiles, Usuarios, Customer, Mps, Poliza and Servicios together something like a foreach but I have no concrete idea, could you help me?

**SQL STATEMENTS**

```
$sqlpermsPer = "INSERT INTO t_perfiles_permisos (Id_Perfil, Area_Permiso, Buscar, Crear, Eliminar, Modificar)
                                            VALUES ($idPerfil,'Perfiles',0,0,0,0)";
$resultpermsPer = $this->dbConnect->query($sqlpermsPer) or die ($sqlpermsPer);

sqlpermsC = "INSERT INTO t_perfiles_permisos (Id_Perfil, Area_Permiso, Buscar, Crear, Eliminar, Modificar)
                                            VALUES ($idPerfil,'Clientes',0,0,0,0)";
$resultpermsC = $this->dbConnect->query($sqlpermsC) or die ($sqlpermsC);

$sqlpermsU = "INSERT INTO t_perfiles_permisos (Id_Perfil, Area_Permiso, Buscar, Crear, Eliminar, Modificar)
                                            VALUES ($idPerfil,'Usuarios',0,0,0,0)";
$resultpermsU = $this->dbConnect->query($sqlpermsU) or die ($sqlpermsU);

$sqlpermsM = "INSERT INTO t_perfiles_permisos (Id_Perfil, Area_Permiso, Buscar, Crear, Eliminar, Modificar)
                                            VALUES ($idPerfil,'Mps',0,0,0,0)";
$resultpermsM = $this->dbConnect->query($sqlpermsM) or die ($sqlpermsM);

$sqlpermsP = "INSERT INTO t_perfiles_permisos (Id_Perfil, Area_Permiso, Buscar, Crear, Eliminar, Modificar)
                                            VALUES ($idPerfil,'Poliza',0,0,0,0)";
$resultpermsP = $this->dbConnect->query($sqlpermsP) or die ($sqlpermsP);

$sqlpermsS = "INSERT INTO t_perfiles_permisos (Id_Perfil, Area_Permiso, Buscar, Crear, Eliminar, Modificar)
                                            VALUES ($idPerfil,'Servicio',0,0,0,0)";
$resultpermsS = $this->dbConnect->query($sqlpermsS) or die ($sqlpermsS);
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You're using PDO in such a way that it is open to sql injection.

Comment: Sure, In this statements I haven't change query() instead prepare() and bindParam but using prepare() and bindParam... that way i can solve it?

Comment: It should be easy to create a function that takes an associative array, and table string as parameters, and then creates the insert. Should be prettier.

Comment: Voted to close as duplicate. See [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query) and [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060721/pdo-mysql-insert-multiple-rows-in-one-query).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This creates an array containing your strings, and loops through them, executing the same query with the bound parameters each time.

```
$stmt = $this->dbConnect->prepare("INSERT INTO t_perfiles_permisos (Id_Perfil, Area_Permiso, Buscar, Crear, Eliminar, Modificar) VALUES (:idPerfil,:str,0,0,0,0)");
$stmt->bindParam(':idPerfil', $idPerfil);
$stmt->bindParam(':str',$val);
$in_arr = array("Perfiles","Clientes","Usuarios","Mps","Poliza","Servicio");

foreach ($in_arr as $key => $val) {
    $stmt->execute();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO
  table 
    (column_one, column_two) 
  VALUES
    ('value_one_one', 'value_one_two'), 
    ('value_two_one', 'value_two_two'), 
    ('value_three_one', 'value_three_two');
```

Answer (score 0):

As long as you terminate each `INSERT` properly you can concatenate them. The following code example also makes use of `prepare` to prevent SQL injection.

```
$sql  = "INSERT INTO t_perfiles_permisos (Id_Perfil, Area_Permiso, Buscar, Crear, Eliminar, Modificar) VALUES (:idPerfil,'Perfiles',0,0,0,0);";
ssql .= "INSERT INTO t_perfiles_permisos (Id_Perfil, Area_Permiso, Buscar, Crear, Eliminar, Modificar) VALUES (:idPerfil,'Clientes',0,0,0,0);";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO t_perfiles_permisos (Id_Perfil, Area_Permiso, Buscar, Crear, Eliminar, Modificar) VALUES (:idPerfil,'Usuarios',0,0,0,0);";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO t_perfiles_permisos (Id_Perfil, Area_Permiso, Buscar, Crear, Eliminar, Modificar) VALUES (:idPerfil,'Mps',0,0,0,0);";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO t_perfiles_permisos (Id_Perfil, Area_Permiso, Buscar, Crear, Eliminar, Modificar) VALUES (:idPerfil,'Poliza',0,0,0,0);";
$sql .= "INSERT INTO t_perfiles_permisos (Id_Perfil, Area_Permiso, Buscar, Crear, Eliminar, Modificar) VALUES (:idPerfil,'Servicio',0,0,0,0);";

try
{
  if ( $stmt = $db->prepare( $sql ) )
  {
    if ( ! $stmt->execute( array( ':idPerfil' => $idPerfil ) )
      error_log( $stmt->errorInfo() );
  }
}
catch ( PDOException $e )
{
  error_log( $e->getMessage() );
}
```

Comment: PDO does not support multiple statements in a single `execute()` call. This will fail with a MySQL syntax error.

Comment: I do it all the time. The only difference here is that this is using `(column) VALUES` syntax which I never do. Not sure that would make a difference.

Comment: A quick search on the subject; http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6346674/pdo-support-for-multiple-queries-pdo-mysql-pdo-mysqlnd

Answer (score -1):

Please check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1176352/pdo-prepared-inserts-multiple-rows-in-single-query).

You might wish to execute a **multiple-insert statement** like this:

```
$qry = 'INSERT INTO table (FirstName, LastName) VALUES ';
$qry .= "(?,?), "
      . "(?,?), "
      . "(?,?)  "
      ;
```