# merge two arrays with numeric keys for values of associative array to insert in MySQL in multiple rows

Tags: php, mysql, arrays, merge, associative-array

I'm getting two arrays $post_img & $post_sort resulting:

```
 Array
(
    [0] => test1.jpg
    [1] => test2.jpg
    [2] => test3.jpg
)
Array
(
    [0] => 3
    [1] => 1
    [2] => 2
)
```

I'd like to merge them like:

```
Array
(
    [Image] => Array
        (
            [0] => test1.jpg
            [1] => test2.jpg
            [2] => test3.jpg
        )
    [Sort] => Array
        (
            [0] => 3
            [1] => 1
            [2] => 2
        )
)
```

Because I think its the best way to insert them into my Database each entry in one row like:

```
ID | Image       | Sort 
1    test1.jpg     3
2    test2.jpg     1
3    test3.jpg     2
```

The point is that I think this should be possible with only one query. 
I had different tries but none of them ended up good.

Comment: Can you show the inserting code here? It's not a problem to make array of arrays: `$arr = array('image' => $post_img, 'sort' => $post_sort);`, but it's only the beginning.

Comment: how to insert this is exactly what I'm searching for with only one query. (Sorry for my confusing question!)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `array`:

```
$newarray = array('Image' => $post_img, 'Sort' => $post_sort);
```

For adding the data to your table, you can go with your original arrays:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO tablename SET Image=:image, Sort=:sort";
$dbImgInsert = $db->prepare($sql); // preparing sql for insert, using parameters

$c = count($post_img)-1;

for ($i=0;$i<=$c;$i++;) { // looping through the arrays

    $dbImgInsert->execute(array(   // inserting the data into the prepared query and into the db
        'image' => $post_img[$i],
        'sort' => $post_sort[$i]
        ));
} // for
```

The above example assumes you are using MySQL with PDO.

To create a single INSERT-statement the classic way, go:

```
$sql="";
$c = count($post_img)-1;
for ($i=0;$i<=$c;$i++;) { // looping through the arrays

    $sql.="('{$post_img[$i]}', '{$post_sort[$i]}'), ";
}
$sql ="INSERT INTO tablename (Image, Sort) VALUES " . trim($sql,',');
```

Comment: That could cause some bottlenecks for large arrays. A few hundred insert statements is not something you want every visitor on your site doing with each page refresh.

Comment: @Husman do you have experience with large arrays and prepared statements? it's only the parameters that get passed, I wonder how performance is compared to mysql_*

Comment: Each PDOStatement::execute() statement is a seperately run mysql query with different parameters. So that for loop would run 200 times, if count($post_img) == 200.

Comment: @michi Thanks for the examples. In the second example shouldn't it be '$sql="";' and in the third line 'for ($i=0;$i<=$c;$i++) {' ?

Comment: Actually that solution was suitable for me (because unfortunately I could not use MarkBaker's because of PHP5.2) - in fact easy, thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Using a [multiple iterator](http://php.net/manual/en/class.multipleiterator.php)

```
$mi = new MultipleIterator();
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($post_img));
$mi->attachIterator(new ArrayIterator($post_sort));

foreach ( $mi as $value ) {
    list($filename, $sortOrder) = $value;
    echo $filename , ' => ' , $sortOrder , '<br />';
}
```

might make it easier to process both arrays at the same time for your database inserts

Comment: +1 Real classy (and, I heard, will be implemented even more 'nativy' in PHP 5.5).

Comment: thats a good approach but unfortunately I'm not working on PHP >= 5.3.0

Comment: @maisch - you really should get your ISP to update then, PHP5.2 is officially unsupported, and PHP5.3 support is now approaching its official end

Comment: @MarkBaker You're so right! Just had a try because of the new crypt algorithms - but until now I have to get on with PHP5.2

Comment: @maisch - It's a pain for me too.... as a developer of OpenSource PHP libraries, I still need to maintain 5.2 compatibility because so many ISP's won't upgrade :(

Answer (score 0):

There is no point merging the arrays, you can just do a SQL statement like so:

```
INSERT INTO tbl (Image, Sort) VALUES
($post_img[0], $post_sort[0]),
($post_img[1], $post_sort[1]),
($post_img[2], $post_sort[2]),
($post_img[3], $post_sort[3])
```

The latter half of that query can be generated using a loop of some sort.

Comment: wrap at least $post_img in ''

Comment: No need, this is the generic statement, not something that should be plugged into his code. However he decides to implement this statement (hopefully no the deprecated mysql* way), his code will take into account data types.

Comment: See the top answer here (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060721/pdo-mysql-insert-multiple-rows-in-one-query) - for one way to achieve this