# SQLSTATE[HY093]: All parameters are filled properly and the syntax is right?

Tags: php, mysql

I am getting the following error:

`SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens in`

Here's the code:

```
$transactions_sql = "INSERT INTO transactions (usr, service, txn_id, orig_amount, currency, date, description, fee_amt, 
  fee_currency, fee_descr, fee_type, net_amt, status) VALUES ";
$transactions_sql_data = array_fill(0, count($transactions), "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$transactions_sql .= implode(",", $transactions_sql_data);
$stmt = $conn->prepare($transactions_sql);
$i = 1;
foreach ($transactions["data"] as $tr) {
  $stmt->bindValue($i++, $id, PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue($i++, $tr["service"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue($i++, $tr["id"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue($i++, $tr["amount"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue($i++, $tr["currency"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue($i++, $tr["created"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue($i++, $tr["description"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue($i++, $tr["fee_details"][0]["amount"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue($i++, $tr["fee_details"][0]["currency"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue($i++, $tr["fee_details"][0]["description"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue($i++, $tr["fee_details"][0]["type"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
  $stmt->bindValue($i++, $tr["net"], PDO::PARAM_INT);
  $stmt->bindValue($i++, $tr["status"], PDO::PARAM_STR);
}
$stmt->execute();
```

Doing `var_dump($transactions_sql)` prints `"INSERT INTO balance_transactions (usr, service, txn_id, orig_amount, currency, date, description, fee_amt, fee_currency, fee_descr, fee_type, net_amt, status) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?),(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)"`, which is correct (in terms of number of question marks - there will only be three arrays inside the `$tr` array).

Comment: The first argument to `bindValue` is constant across loop iterations, so it looks like the next set of values replaces the previous one instead of being added as new parameters

Comment: That would be weird, because I used [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10060755/1079641) for reference.

Comment: When he uses constant parameter names, he executes the statement once for each loop iteration, so the parameters don't collide. In the single query example, he uses `$i++` instead of constant integers so that the same index doesn't get reused

Comment: Can you check this ? `$stmt->bindValue(2, tr["service"], PDO::PARAM_STR);` . isn't it a `$tr["service"]` ?

Comment: `count($transactions) - 1` < why that `- 1`?

Comment: @RalphJohnGalindo that was a type when copying over. Still the same result.

Comment: @bwoebi Mistake on my part. Still same result.

Comment: @mzulch I updated my question with that code and it still throws the same warning/error.

Comment: Just edited. Typed wrong again! But same error continues...

Comment: @bwoebi Looks like I needed to add that `-1` when counting the `$transactions` array. Otherwise, it was adding 1 too many set of parameters.

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I had to add a `-1` to `count($transactions)` for it to work. Looks like it was adding 1 too many set of parameters.

Here's what worked:
`$transactions_sql_data = array_fill(0, count($transactions), "(?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");`

Thanks to everyone else for helping out!